# Hmisc's latex(): na.blank not working as expected; spurious empty column; how to get groups in columns?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with names "d", "n", "beta", "family", "alpha", and "value". I would like to create a LaTeX table with `Hmisc::latex`, where the first three columns contain the variables "d", "n", and "beta" which give the corresponding row names. The other variables ("family", "alpha") should be displayed in the remaining columns (each of "F1" and "F2" -- the elements of family -- defines a group; for each of these two groups, the different values of alpha define columns; overall, there are thus 2 * 3 = 6 columns containing the corresponding "value"). Here is what I have so far:

```
## running parameters
nn <- length(n <- c(100, 500)) # sample sizes
nd <- length(d <- c(10, 100, 1000)) # dimensions
nfamily <- length(family <- c("F1", "F2")) # families
nbeta <- length(beta <- c(0.25, 0.75)) # betas
nalpha <- length(alpha <- c(0.95, 0.99, 0.999)) # alphas

## create array containing the results
res <- array(NA, dim=c(nn, nd, nfamily, nbeta, nalpha),
             dimnames=list(n=n, d=d, family=family, beta=beta, alpha=alpha))
set.seed(1)
for(i in 1:nn){
    for(j in 1:nd){
        for(k in 1:nfamily){
            for(l in 1:nbeta){
                for(m in 1:nalpha){
                    res[i,j,k,l,m] <- i+j+k+l+m+runif(1) # some dummy values
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

## create a data.frame from the array of values
df <- as.data.frame.table(res, responseName="value")

## sort it according to the variables you want to display in the rows and bring the
## corresponding columns to the front/beginning
row.vars <- c("d", "n", "beta") # specify row variables
df. <- df[with(df, do.call(order, sapply(row.vars, as.name))), # sort rows
          c(row.vars, setdiff(names(df), row.vars))] # sort colums

## format numbers, set unwanted row names to NA
df.. <- df.
df..$value <- formatC(df.$value, digits=3, format="f")
names2NA <- function(x) {x[c(FALSE, x[-1]==x[-length(x)])] <- NA; x} # arg = TRUE <=> entry equal to previous one
for(j in 1:length(row.vars)) df..[, row.vars[j]] <- names2NA(df..[, row.vars[j]])

## now use Hmisc's latex()
require(Hmisc)
latex(df.., title="title",
      file="",
      label="tab:res",
      cgroup=c("family", "alpha"),
      na.blank=TRUE, # use blanks rather than NA => not working (see first columns)!
      rowname=NULL,
      colheads=c("Family", "alpha"), # character() specifying column headings
      dcolumn=TRUE,
      booktabs=TRUE,
      caption="My table containing all results.",
      caption.loc="bottom",
      collabel.just=rep("c", 2),
      where="htbp",
      center="centering",
      type="verbatim",
      helvetica=FALSE
      )
```

Here are my questions:

1) Why are the NAs in the first three columns not replaced by blanks (as should be the case for `na.blank=TRUE`)?

2) Why is an emtpy fourth column inserted?

3) How can I obtain the variables "family" and "alpha" as groups in the columns as described above?

**Update**

In the meanwhile, I managed to convert the data.frame to a matrix. I have similar problems with that, I posted that here (since it is more specific): [Hmisc: How to group column variables with latex()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408869/hmisc-how-to-group-column-variables-with-latex)

Answer (score 1):

I only have an answer to question 1.

Apparently the na.blank=TRUE only applies to numeric columns, not character or factor. This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere but I found out in this very easy example.

```
x <- data.frame(c(1, NA, NA), c("cow", NA, NA), factor(c("chicken", NA, NA)))
names(x) <- c("numeric", "character", "factor")
library(Hmisc)
latex(x, file = '', na.blank = TRUE)
```

If you run the code you see that the NAs in the numeric column become blank, while the NAs in the other columns become "NA". I don't know the reason for this behavior. It is however easy to remedy by replacing the NA's in character and factor columns by "" before running the latex command.

In your code the first few columns are factor so the above applies.