# Hmisc: How to group column variables with latex()?

Tags: r

How can I use `Hmisc`'s `latex` to obtain a table like ...

```
                        Group 1                     Group 2
d   n   beta   Sub-group 1   Sub-group 2   Sub-group 1   Sub-group 2
10  100 0.25       1             9
        0.75       2
    500 0.25       3            10
        0.75       4            11             ...           ...
100 100 0.25       5            12
        0.75       6            13
    500 0.25       7            ...
        0.75       8
```

...? Below is what I have so far. Somehow I would like to tell `latex` to use the
first three columns as to display the row labels. Also, the NA is not removed.

```
x <- matrix(1:72, ncol=4, nrow=8) # data part
colnames(x) <- c("gr1.sgr1", "gr1.sgr2", "gr2.sgr1", "gr2.sgr2")
rmNames <- function(x) {x[c(FALSE, x[-1]==x[-length(x)])] <- ""; x} 
rn <- apply(expand.grid(beta=c(0.25, 0.75), n=c(100, 500), d=c(10, 100))[, 3:1], 2, rmNames)
x <- cbind(rn, x) 
x[2,5] <- NA

require(Hmisc)
latex(x,
      file="",
      cgroup=c("", "Group 1", "Group 2"),
      n.cgroup=c(3, 2, 2),
      na.blank=TRUE,
      rowlabel=c("d", "n", "beta"),
      booktabs=TRUE,
      collabel.just=rep("c", 2))
```

**Update**

With joran's approach, I obtain (so adding `rownames=NULL` and `rep("c",7)`):

```
\begin{table}[!tbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lllcllcll}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries }&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries }&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Group 1}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries }&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Group 2}
\tabularnewline
\cline{1-9}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{d}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{n}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{beta}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{gr1.sgr1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{gr1.sgr2}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{gr2.sgr1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{gr2.sgr2}\tabularnewline
\midrule
10&100&0.25&&1&9&&17&25\tabularnewline
&&0.75&&2&NA&&18&26\tabularnewline
&500&0.25&&3&11&&19&27\tabularnewline
&&0.75&&4&12&&20&28\tabularnewline
100&100&0.25&&5&13&&21&29\tabularnewline
&&0.75&&6&14&&22&30\tabularnewline
&500&0.25&&7&15&&23&31\tabularnewline
&&0.75&&8&16&&24&32\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

1) Why are empty columns inserted (`\multicolumn{1}{c}{}`)?

2) Why are the `NA`s not replaced?

Comment: Adding `rowname = NULL` and changing the last argument to `rep("c",7)` appears to work for me. (Although I had to modify your code somewhat, since I don't have the `rmNames` function.)

Comment: Hi joran, thanks for helping me. I put in `rmNames` (sorry for the inconvenience) and updated the post. I am wondering why empty columns are inserted and why `NA`s are not replaced by strings `""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's a coercion problem in `rmNames`. You probably meant for it to be:

```
rmNames <- function(x) {x[c(FALSE, x[-1]==x[-length(x)])] <- NA; x}
```

Assigning empty characters ends up coercing everything to character. I'm honestly not quite sure how that causes `latex` to trip up, because the value in question is still an NA, but making that change seems to fix things.

As for the extra columns, I don't know. Looking at the resulting PDFs, I can only hypothesize that the author believes that when grouping columns it looks nicer to pad them with empty columns, and I confess they might have a point if that's true.